# Django authentication problem - how can I force active users to setup a profile first?

Tags: django, forms, require, django-registration

I've put myself into somewhat of a pickle. I use django-registration often, and it seems to work for most situations.  However, I want to require users to build their profile (eg: demographic information) *before they can visit any of the other pages*.

This is how I desire the current setup to run:

1. *visitor fills out registration form* --(submit)--->
2. *user email verification* --(link creates active user)--->
3. --(redirected to profile view)--->
4. *user fills out profile form* --(submit)-->
5. *user can now access the rest of the website*

Is there a recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the ways of doing it would be to use your own `@profile_required` decorator rather than the django's built in `login_required` on all your views.

```
@login_required
def profile_required(func,request,*args,**kwargs):
    has_profile = request.user.profile_set.count()
    if not has_profile:
        return redirect('create_profile')
    return func(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

Then on each view you want to have a user with profile visit, just:

```
@profile_required
def my_awesome_view(request):
    ...
```